# Excel: How to obtain depured colum B after deleting matching values from column A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have in Column A a Blacklist of sites that i can not use any more
In column B i have listed all of my current sites (more than 5000 rows).

So i need to look if any of the values of column A is listed in B and if so, delete it or highlight so i can later delete it and obtain a final WHITELIST, with all sites except the ones listed in Column A-

Help anyone?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is not a script/formula writing service. However, it is a Q&A site where you can ask a specific question about something you have attempted and get stuck. There is a reasonable expectation you would have already tried something and not expect us to do it for you. With that being said, please [edit] your question to include what you have research and attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a lookup function in column C to compare sites from column B to the blacklisted in A. Something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,A:A,1,0)
```

If a match is found you will get the site name from A as a result, otherwise the formula will return #N/A. Then you only need to select columns B and C and sort by C. You should get the blacklisted sites in the top rows of column C, so you can delete them easily.

It's kind of a "savage" solution, I know, but it's pretty easy and quick.